# Calling a variable within a class from a method in the class in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

```py
class a_class():
    a_class_variable = 1

    @classmethod
    def a_class_method(cls):
        print(a_class.a_class_variable)

a_variable = a_class()
a_variable.a_class_method()
```

I was just looking up calling a variable of a class inside a method within that class and I found it but, why is it that you need to name the class that the method is within when the method is in the same class?

Shouldn't the variable be visible to the method without doing so as the method is within the same class as the variable?

I can see this as being needed if you're calling a variable in a different class. For example `b_class()`.

Is there some Pythonic reason for this convention?

Comment: You should use `cls.a_class_variable`.  Note that this will pick up the variable from whatever class the method is invoked on - which might be a subclass of `a_class`.  (If you don't want or need that feature, you should have used a staticmethod instead of a classmethod).

Comment: No.  These are just functions, and the current class member variables are not part of the function's local namespace.  Same thing as `self`.

Comment: Your assumption is that the `class` statement defines a scope in which a variable named `a_class_variable` is defined; that's not true. The *namespace* where `a_class_variable` is initialized is only temporary, until the class is created. Names in that namespace become class attributes, but no scope is ever defined. Inside `a_class_method`, `a_class_variable` alone refers to something in the enclosing scope, which is where `a_class` is defined, not the namespace inside the statement that defines `a_class`.

Comment: What chepner said:  the scope visibility of the enclosing namespace (i.e. globals or closures doesn't work exactly the same way with classes).  You are expected to use `self`, `cls` or <classname> to refer to those class variables *from within a method*.  However, `a_class_variable_plusone = a_class_variable + 1` would be valid code at the *class's level*.

Comment: I was under the false impression from my own self leaning that it was interpreted the other way around **[built-ins, global, enclosing, local]**.  I found an article talking about the  **[local, enclosing, global, built-ins]** rule.